# Date Time format in Flutter like Today / dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to add DateFormat in flutter like

```
Today / dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm
```

How can I do this and compare it to List items depend on the date

```
//  This is the item I want to list depends on the date 
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data.expenseList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TransactionIncome(
            index: index,
            expense: data.expenseList[index],
        );
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add intl package to your pubspec.yaml

Then import it

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Then use this method to parse your date "yourDateValue"

```
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("Today / dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
final String formatted = formatter.format(yourDateValue);
```

Comment: I already add intl to the pubspec i working with it but i want a date format like  today/7:27 PM format or yesterday/11:25 AM format

Answer (score 0):

You can get the formated date and time as you mentioned by following the method

add these to pubspec.yaml file

```
  intl: ^0.17.0
  date_format: ^2.0.5
```

and implement it like;

```
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.now();
 var nowFormatedDate = DateFormat.yMd().format(nowTime).toString();
var nowFormatedTme = formatDate(
    DateTime(2019, 08, 1, nowTime.hour, nowTime.minute),
    [hh, ':', nn, " ", am]).toString();
var formatedDateTime = nowFormatedDate + ' / ' + nowFormatedTme;
print(formatedDateTime);
```

Note: User your own time instead of nowTime